# How to write a stdout statement in a .log file in spring boot application

Tags: java, logging, spring-boot

- I am trying to write System.out.print statement in log file
- I use the following application.properties file

> logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO
>
> logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
>
> logging.level.com.cirq.configurator=INFO
>
> logging.path=${mypath}
>
> logging.file=filename.log

- But using the above code, I am not able to write System.out.print statement in the log file
- First, I create .jar file of my spring-boot project and run in undertow application server
- Please help me....
  Thanks in advance

Comment: Using sysout/syserr for logging is not a good practice. But not catching up sysout/syserr info into the logging system is even worse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you are deploying .jar file in undertow application server, then System.out.print statement will not work(means it will not write in log file).

For that you have to use log4j which is in-built in Spring Boot.

Example:

`final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(YourController.class);`

`logger.info("Your print statement");`

Refer [link](https://springframework.guru/using-log4j-2-spring-boot/)

Comment: can I create multiple log file using this code...??

Comment: Actually I want to generate .log file according to date

Comment: although this 'works' as mentioned, it does not address the real question 'how to direct sysout/syserr to the logging system'

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this dependency in your pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>uk.org.lidalia</groupId>
   <artifactId>sysout-over-slf4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Then in the main method before you do anything call this code:

`SysOutOverSLF4J.sendSystemOutAndErrToSLF4J();`

That way anything that is written in sysout or syserr gets caught in the logging system